# Mysql - Compare int field with comma separated field from another table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in a MySQL database like this:

## User:

```
userid     |userid      | Username     | Plan(VARCHAR) | Status  |
-----------+------------+--------------+---------------+---------+
1          | 1          |  John        | 1,2,3         |1        |
2          | 2          |  Cynthia     | 1,2           |1        |
3          | 3          |  Charles     | 2,3,4         |1        |
```

## Plan: (planid is primary key)

```
planid(INT)  |  Plan_Name     | Cost     |  status      | 
-------------+----------------+----------+--------------+
1            |  Tamil Pack    |  100     |  ACTIVE      |
2            |  English Pack  |  100     |  ACTIVE      |
3            |  SportsPack    |  100     |  ACTIVE      |
4            |  KidsPack      |  100     |  ACTIVE      |
```

## OUTPUT

```
id |userid | Username | Plan       | Planname                            |
---+-------+----------+------------+-------------------------------------+
1  | 1     |  John    | 1,2,3      |Tamil Pack,English Pack,SportsPack   |
2  | 2     |  Cynthia | 1,2        |Tamil Pack,English Pack              |
3  | 3     |  Charles | 2,3,4      |English Pack,Sportspack, Kidspack    |
```

Since plan id in Plan table is integer and the user can hold many plans, its stored as comma separated as varchar, so when i try with IN condition its not working.

```
SELECT * FROM plan WHERE find_in_set(plan_id,(select user.planid from user where user.userid=1))
```

This get me the 3 rows from plan table but i want the desired output as above.

How to do that.? any help Please

Comment: "Since plan id in Plan table is integer and the user can hold many plans, its stored as comma separated as varchar, so when i try with IN condition its not working. " If this is a new project you should stop the comma separted values madness and normalize the table structures and add the table `User_Plan` that holds the relations.

Comment: Please read my answer to this question: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574#3653574)

Answer (score 0):

A rewrite off your query what should work is as follows..

**Query**

```
SELECT
   all columns you need
 , GROUP_CONCAT(Plan.Plan_Name ORDER BY Plan.planid) AS Planname
FROM
  Plan
WHERE
  FIND_IN_SET(Plan.plan_id,(
    SELECT
      User.Plan
    FROM
      user
    WHERE User.userid = 1
  )
)
GROUP BY
  all columns what are in the select (NOT the GROUP_CONCAT function)
```

You also can use `FIND_IN_SET` on the `ON` clause off a `INNER JOIN`.
One problem is that the join won't ever use indexes.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
   all columns you need
 , GROUP_CONCAT(Plan.Plan_Name ORDER BY Plan.planid) AS Planname
FROM 
 User 
INNER JOIN 
 Plan
ON
 FIND_IN_SET(Plan.id, User.Plan)
WHERE 
 User.id = 1
GROUP BY
 all columns what are in the select (NOT the GROUP_CONCAT function)
```

Like i said in the comments you should normalize the table structures and add the table `User_Plan` whats holds the relations between the table `User` and `Plan`.